# The specified module 'SQLPS' was not loaded in azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-2.0, azure-sql-database, sqlps

I create new Azure VM and i want to invoke some SQL Powershell commands like `Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking`. I have not install any sql server in VM, because i want to do operation on my azure database. so i need to install any sql server for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to install SQL Server on the VM. But, you need to have Azure PowerShell and the SQLDB PowerShell cmdlets on the VM. I'd suggest to start by installing the Azure SDK. This link has more information on the steps: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-sql-database-management-with-powershell/

Hope this helps.

Torsten

Comment: I have Azure Powershell but i want install SQLDB PowerShell cmdlets, you know how to install that.